# How to alter a stored procedure using vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, alter

I am creating an application that will allow me to deploy a stored procedure to multiple databases at once. The code first checks whether or not the stored procedure already exists in the target database. If it already exists, it should alter the procedure, if it doesn't exist, it should create the procedure. Here's what the code looks like:

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common

'----------------------------------------------
' First I create the stored procedure object
'----------------------------------------------
Dim srv As New Server(serverName)
Dim db  As Database = srv.Databases(databaseName)
Dim sp  As New StoredProcedure(db, procedureName)

Try
    sp.TextMode               = False
    sp.AnsiNullStatus         = True
    sp.QuotedIdentifierStatus = True

    ' Add Parameters
    For i As Integer = 0 to parameterList.Items.Count - 1
        Dim nextParam As New StoredProcedureParameter(sp, parameterList.Items(i), typeList.items(i))
        sp.Parameters.Add(nextParam)
    Next

    ' Add the body
    sp.TextBody = procedureText
Catch ex As Exception
    Exit Sub
End Try

'---------------------------------------------------------------------
' Then I check to see if the procedure already exists in the database
'---------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim sqlConnection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
Dim cmd           As New SqlCommand
Dim reader        As SqlDataReader
Dim procsInDB     As New List(Of String)

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.Connection  = sqlConnection
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CAST(routine_name AS VARCHAR(200)) FROM information_schema.routines WHERE routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'"

sqlConnection.Open()
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

If reader.HasRows then
    Do While reader.Read()
        procsInDB.Add(reader.GetString(0))
    Loop
End If

'-------------------------------------------------------------
' Now I run either the Create() or Alter() based on whether
' the stored procedure already exists in the database
'-------------------------------------------------------------
If procsInDB.IndexOf(sp.Name) = -1 then
    sp.Create()
Else
    sp.Alter()
End If
```

When I run this code against a database that doesn't have the stored procedure, it calls the sp.Create() command and it works fine. When I run the code against a database that already has the procedure, it calls sp.Alter() but it gives me this error:

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.InvalidSmoOperationException: You cannot perform operation Alter on an object in state Creating.

As far as I've been able to tell, I'm getting this error because the sp Object I declared hasn't yet called the Create() Method, so it can't be altered with the Alter() method. But if the stored procedure already exists, I don't want to create it, I only want to alter it. Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Comment: Have you considered checking the existence prior to starting to create it?

Comment: Because you cannon modify a SP that does not exist in the SQL Server. You code object at that point is just an object definition that has not been created.

Comment: This declaration ''Dim sp  As New StoredProcedure(db, procedureName)'' does not bind and existing object in the server, it onmly provides the name for your new SP.

Comment: Ok, so I could check the existence before declaring the new StoredProcedure instance, but if I find that it exists, how can I alter it?

Comment: I thought of dynamically building a script to alter the procedure and running it using SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(), but I was trying to avoid this because working with the StoredProcedure objects seemed easier and less prone to error

Comment: @starx207 You could simply execute a drop procedure, if it exists, and always end by calling your sp.Create() regardless. In other words, use "IF" only to test if you execute the dropping or not.